Physical realization of Bose-Hubbard model in solid state physics
Are there any supposed physical realizations of the Bose-Hubbard model in solid state physics? Obviously the Fermi version is more relevant to this purpose, but I wonder if there are any materials that in certain phases are known to be described sufficiently well by the Bose-Hubbard model, maybe due to the fact that they can be described in terms of collective excitations which are bosons.
Edit to reply to a previous answer: I am aware that certain platforms such as ultra cold atoms can realize this model and have been used to study for instance the superfluid-Mott transition (https://www.nature.com/articles/415039a). I am more interested in the realization of Hubbard model physics in solid state materials.

Technically qualifying but probably not what you meant, pt 1: superconducting transmon arrays can also realize the Bose-Hubbard model in a quantum simulation context, see e.g. https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-024-07325-z?fromPaywallRec=false

Technically qualifying but probably not what you meant, pt 2: thin films of superfluid He: https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.50.6515

Thanks a lot for the references, even though it is not exactly what j meant it is still really useful especially for thin films of superfluid He, i wasnt aware of such possibility. Weirdly I cannot get acces for the moment to that paper but ill look more in to it. Thanks!
